# Retaining the state of the component if the data uploaded to the server fails - react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux with react native. I have a form where users can dynamically add the no of fields. Hence there is a separate component class for the input fields so that it can be added later as required. After submitting the data to the server, the state of the inputs of the component is empty whether it succeeds or not. How to retain the states if the data upload to the server fails?

Thanks in advance.

SignUp.js

```
import SignUpUserInfo from './Common/SignUpUserInfo';

var index = 0;
class SignUp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    myArr: [],
  }

  _onPressOut() {
    let temp = index ++
    this.state.myArr.push(temp)
    this.setState({
        myArr: this.state.myArr
    })
   }

  render() {
    if (this.state.myArr.length < 1) {
      let temp = index;
      this.state.myArr.push(temp);
      this.setState({
          myArr: this.state.myArr,
      });
    }

    let Arr = this.state.myArr.map((a, i) => {
      return <SignUpUserInfo key={i} {...this.props} />;
    });

    if (signUpFetching) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color= {'green'} />;
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={[{ backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9' }]}>
          { Arr }
          <View style={CommonStyle.bottomGap}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressOut()}>
              <Text>Register more people</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={CommonStyle.horizontalGap}>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                this.props.SignUpTest(this.state.resultArr);
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 10, }}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Sign Up</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { Name, Designation, signUpFetching } = state.Auth; //how to get name & designation for multiple people here?
  return { Name, Designation, signUpFetching };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { AuthGet, SignUpTest })(SignUp);
```

SignUpUserInfo.js //includes required inputs to be added by users

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      SignUpDesignation: '',
    };
}

render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter Your Name'}
          onChangeText={text => {
             //'Name' prop should be different for different input.How to do that?
            this.onNameChange(`Name`, text);
          }}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Designation'}
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.onDesignationChange(`Designation`, text);
            }
          }
          value={this.state.SignUpDesignation}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpUserInfo;
```

Action

```
export const AuthGet = ({prop, value}) => {
  return ({
    type: SIGN_UP_GET,
    payload: {prop, value},
  });
};

export const SignUpTest = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_UP_INITIAL,
    });
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: baseUrl + signUpUrl,
      data: {
        memberDetails: JSON.stringify(data),
      },
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.data.status === 'true') {
        dispatch({
          type: SIGN_UP_SUCCESS,
          payload: response.data,
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: SIGN_UP_FAILURE,
          payload: response.data.message,
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_UP_FAILURE,
        payload: 'Smth went wrong',
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  Name: '',
  Designation: '',
  signUpFetching: false,
  signUpResponse: [],
  signUpErr: '',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case SIGN_UP_GET:
      return { ...state, [actions.payload.prop]: actions.payload.value};
    case SIGN_UP_INITIAL:
      return { ...state, signUpFetching: true, signUpResponse: [], signUpErr: '' };
    case SIGN_UP_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, signUpFetching: false, signUpResponse: actions.payload, signUpErr: '' };
    case SIGN_UP_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, signUpFetching: false, signUpErr: actions.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the text field values from the local state to redux store, and reset the values to empty strings when the data upload is successful, in reducer at
`SIGN_UP_SUCCESS`, you can reset the text field values in the redux state.